# Is it possible to loop through a classes members in java?

Tags: java, dto

I have a DTO that has a whole bunch of members. I was wondering if Java supports the idea of a for(in) for the class.  I don't think it does, but it would save me a ton of grief if it did, so, I figured I'd toss the question out there.

Comment: You're asking this on a question which was answered 3.5 years ago?!  A      DTO is an object used to represent a data set, usually associated with a corollary db table. I was using here with Spring. I presume it's used in most JDBC situations.

Comment: As a matter of fact I am :)  What's 3.5 years in the larger scheme of things in timeless cyberspace?  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: sure glad I can be of use. Here's some more reading on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, you can do it with reflection:

```
for (Field field : clazz.getFields())
{
    ...
}
```

(Or the equivalent for methods etc.)

You can then get the field values for a specific instance, or static values.

Answer (score 7):

It does, it a bit of hassle though.

You have to use reflection.

See: [Class.getDeclaredFieds()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

> *Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object*

You can see an example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/examplets/java.lang.reflect/110.html)

> *There are three ways of obtaining a Field object from a Class object.*

```
 Class cls = java.awt.Point.class;

 // By obtaining a list of all declared fields.
 Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();

 // By obtaining a list of all public fields, 
 // both declared and inherited.
 fields = cls.getFields();
 for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
   Class type = fields[i].getType();
   process(fields[i]);
 }

 // By obtaining a particular Field object.
 // This example retrieves java.awt.Point.x.
 try {
   Field field = cls.getField("x");
   process(field);
   } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
 }
```

See the [Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class definition for more options.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the [Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html). Particularly, check the `getFields` and `getMethods` methods from [`Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get all the members and functions.

Maybe you need to ask yourself why that DTO has so many members that you think this is necessary.  Could be time to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the reflection framework whereby you can introspect the class for this information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html